# Pygtk nested entries and notebook control

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, glade

Greeting

I am having a difficulty in retrieving entry text from the first page of a notebook in the main window.
I tested my code without the notebook, but now with notebook, it either complains cannot convert string to float or the code fails.

Do i have to take into account the Notebook page or data container stuff

here is what i did (interpreted) if you could help with this i'd appreciate it.

```html
from gi.repository import Gtk , Gio
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange , pi, random, linspace


class main :
   def __init__(self):
      self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
      self.builder.add_from_file("File2.glade")
      self.window=self.builder.get_object("window1")
      self.window2=self.builder.get_object("window2")
      self.ntbk=self.builder.get_object("notebook1")
      sw1=self.builder.get_object('scrolledwindow1')

                self.builder.connect_signals(Handler())
                self.window.show_all()



class Handler:
   def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
      Gtk.main_quit()
   def on_radiobutton1_toggled(self, widget):
                # I will be doing something here
   def on_radiobutton2_toggled(self, widget):
                # I will be doing another thing here
   def on_radiobutton3_toggled(self, widget):
                #  other
       
       try:
            m1=float(main.en1.get_text());
            m2= float(main.en2.get_text());
            m3= float(main.en3.get_text());
        except ValueError:
            print " This is not working "
            return 0
```

So basically it is not reading , it prints "It's not working" , if i take the error handling it will be throw at you , the cannot convert string to float
I appreciate it

Comment: Can you post the glade file you are using or a simplified example that works without a glade file?

Comment: Is it possible to get a working example of how to use notebook (Pygtk 3 with glade builder) with entries in each of its multiple pages. Say i have 4 text entries in the first page, 4 entries in the second page, and 4 entries in third page. Thanks a lot Elya5

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what your problem is. You can retrieve the text from the Gtk.Entry as expected. This behaviour is not changed by the Gtk.Notebook. The conversion to float has nothing to do with `get_text()`. You get a string and if the string does not contain a valid float and you try to convert it, you will get an error.

This is a working example of a Gtk.Notebook with two Gtk.Entries and if you click the Gtk.Button, it will call `get_text()` and try to convert the string to float.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        button = Gtk.Button('Get text')
        button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)

        self.entry1 = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry2 = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry2.set_input_purpose(Gtk.InputPurpose.NUMBER)

        notebook.append_page(self.entry1)
        notebook.append_page(self.entry2)

        box.pack_end(button, True, True, 0)
        box.pack_start(notebook, True, True, 0)
        window.add(box)
        window.show_all()

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        self.try_conversion(self.entry1.get_text())
        self.try_conversion(self.entry2.get_text())

    def try_conversion(self, text):
        try:
            print('Float: {}'.format(float(text)))
        except ValueError:
            print('String: ' + text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example()
    Gtk.main()
```

You should also think about using a Gtk.SpinButton if you only want a number.